# How to change span of QWidget inside a QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets, qsplitter

I have three widgets disposed as this:

[image]

where there is a QSplitter beetween A+B and C

I'm looking for a way to make that, when a certain QPushButton is pressed, Widget C changes its span and lets more space to Widget B, as in this photo:

[image]

I tried to change the span of C inside the splitter, but I didn't found any easy way to do that (as there is with layouts). I tried some things but nothing worked as I want.

Comment: Please show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].  In the first image how are A and B separated; a splitter?

Comment: The two images show very different layout structures. The only way to achieve that would be to have a horizontal layout that only contains the splitter, then remove B from the horizontal layout that also contains A, and add it to the parent horizontal layout right after the splitter. If you need further help, please provide a MRE as requested above (ensure that it's *both* minimal *and* reproducible).

Comment: Ok, I have managed to do that using that idea with the layouts, thanks.

Comment: @FuegoFatuo25 You may consider to answer your own question, including some code. It may be useful to others with the same question.